# To split html code using beautifulsoup for the required format

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML snippet which looks like following:

```
<div class="myTestCode">
<strong>Abc: </strong> test1</br>
<strong>Def: </strong> test2</br>
</div>
```

How do I parse it in Beautiful Soup to get:

```
Abc: test1, Def: test2
```

This is what I have tried so far :

```
data = """<div class="myTestCode">
<strong>Abc: </strong> test1</br>
<strong>Def: </strong> test2</br>
</div>"""
temp = BeautifulSoup(data)
link = temp.select('.myTestCode')

#both didn't print the expected output as mentioned above
print str(link).split('<strong>')
print ''.join(link.stripped_strings)
```

Comment: I tried str(link).split('<strong>') also ''.join(link.stripped_strings) where link  = temp.select('.myTestCode')     . temp = BeautifulSoup(data)

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30093373/edit) your post with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<div class="myTestCode">
<strong>Abc: </strong> test1</br>
<strong>Def: </strong> test2</br>
</div>"""
temp = BeautifulSoup(data)

#get individual <strong> elements
strongs = temp.select('.myTestCode > strong')

#map each <strong> element to it's text content concatenated with the text node that follow
result = map(lambda x: x.text + x.nextSibling.strip(), strongs)

#join all separated by comma and print
print ', '.join(result)

#print output:
#Abc: test1, Def: test2
```